# Express app serving files from 'public' but not 'bower_components'

Tags: express

I have an app built with Express 4. It is serving any files from the `public` directory fine, but throwing a `404` when attempting to access files served from `bower_components`. The dir structure is

```
|--myApp
    |--bin
    |--bower_components
        |--bootstrap
    |--node_modules
    |--public
        |--user
           |--stylesheets
    |--routes
    |--views
    |--app.js
```

In `app.js` I configure accordingly

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
```

and then in my `layout.jade`

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/user/stylesheets/myStyle.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

When the app runs the public assets are served, but not the bower stuff. I look at the `Network` tab in Chrome Dev Tools, and see for `myStyle.css`

```
https://localhost:5000/user/stylesheets/myStyle.css
https://localhost:5000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```